# Upsert/Merge in MemSQL Pipeline

Tags: singlestore

Is there a way to use Upsert/Merge like functionality in MemSQL Pipeline using Procedures.

I tried using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` in the procedure, but my pipeline failed with error `Feature 'INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE for columnar tables' is not supported by MemSQL.`

Let me know if more information is needed.

Thanks,
Santhosh

Answer (score 2):

I spoke to MemSQL Support, This is what they told.

Only way to achieve upserts is to manually write logic to first delete the record if a duplicate key is detected, and then insert the new record.

If you have files in local machine, you can use https://docs.memsql.com/sql-reference/v6.8/load-data/. This takes care of upserts.

Answer (score 1):

MemSQL does not support unique indexes on columnar tables. From https://docs.memsql.com/concepts/v6.8/columnstore/

> *Note that you can only have one CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE key as well as the SHARD KEY. With the exception of metadata-only unenforced unique keys, you cannot add any other key, including PRIMARY KEY, to the columnstore table.*

If it's feasible to change the table from columnar to rowstore, you can create a unique index.

Answer (score 0):

MemSQL 7.1 does support unique constraint which you can define on only one column. you can also add more than one indexes of type HASH other than columnstore index itself.

MemSQL 7.3 is going to have support for UPSERT.